# AWS code build with env variables from build-spec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm new to this code build. I'm trying to define the environment variables in the 'environment variable tab in code build' and use those environment variables defined in buildspec.yml. The objective of doing that is to access in the react app with proces.env.REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE which should provide the value as expected, so that it can be used for API calls.

```
buildspec.yml

env:
 variables:
// I understand this is plain text. But SOME_TOKEN provided below is defined in the aws code build as an environment variable having a value under environment tab
REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN: ${SOME_TOKEN} 
REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE: ${SOME_SPACE}
REACT_APP_BASE_URL: 'https://myurl'
REACT_APP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT: '10000'
REACT_APP_SERVICE_API_KEY: ${SERVICE_API_KEY}
...
phases:
install:
commands:
- echo "Building ${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER}"
...
```

What i see in process.env.REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN for e.g., is just "${SOME_TOKEN}' or whatever that is provided as a plaintext, but not the env value defined for the variable 'REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN' in the environment tab. 
    I tried with the following variations, but nothing is working:

```
REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE: ${SOME_SPACE}
REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE: '${SOME_SPACE}'
REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE: {SOME_SPACE}
REACT_APP_SOME_SPACE: $SOME_SPACE
```

Questions:

1. Is this correct way of doing? If not, Please advise me and provide me details
2. I see that the parameter store in aws is used for storing secret keys. But want to how do I refer it in the process.env or some other env variables in react app, so I can use it my api calls to pass it over.

What I meant by environment tab mean at aws code build.

[image]

Comment: What you do is correct wrt environment variables. If you use parameter store for secrets, use aws ssm get-parameter api to obtain the values. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `variables` is just a mapping  of `key: value`. At that point, environment variables which you specify for the container are not used.

This is exemplified in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) using `$PATH`:

> set an environment variable named PATH with a value of $PATH:/usr/share/ant/bin, then /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin is replaced by the **literal value** $PATH:/usr/share/ant/bin.

Thus your variable `REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN` is set to **literal value** of ${SOME_TOKEN}, explaining why you are getting them as text only values later on.

For example, to set `REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN` to the real value of `${SOME_TOKEN}` the following can be done in the `pre_build`:

```
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - export REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN=${SOME_TOKEN}
```

Alternatively, in your build project you could consider using `REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN` directly, instead of defining `SOME_TOKEN`, which then you assign to `REACT_APP_SOME_TOKEN`.

P.S. Example of sourcing files in bash:

myenvvars.sh:

```
export A=3
export B=4
```

buildspec (mock)

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./myenvvars.sh

echo ${A}
echo ${B}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and the logic behind it made sense. Indeed it resolves. Just exploring the options if it can be exported via a different file if the number of variables increased. At the moment I've 5 to 6 variables to be exported which i'm currently doing based on the solution suggested by you.

Comment: @Brad glad it worked. Yes it should be possible. You can bundle a file with the variables and then [source](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) them in buildspec.yml.

Comment: Should that be another .spec file or can that in any file. Could you pls throw me an example as Its hard to see the documentation available online. Also just wanna know if we use parameter_store, how do we export it?

Comment: @Brad I provided basic example in the answer. You keep your vars in a file, e.g., `myenvvars.sh` and then in your `buildspec` you source it. I don't have real buildspec.yml to test as I'm not running any builds now, but I think the idea should be clear. Obviously you would have to adjust it to real `buildspec.yml` and source in `commands` section.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you once again. You saved this weekend for me. Does the first answer to export the variables works the same way for parameter_store, coz going forward I might end up doing that as well. I read how to include in the parameter_store, but unsure about how to export it.

Comment: @Brad parameter store is generally better, as you don't hard code any secrets into your build files. Also you can easly reuse and change parameter store values between different builds and projects, as you have them in one central location.